# azure documentdb create document duplicates Id property

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to store the following object in azure documentdb

```
public class MyDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherClass SomeOtherClass { get; set; }
}
```

the property Id is a timestamp (yyyyMMddHHmmss) followed by a guid. As a side-effect, this allows me to sort on Id.
I used this call to store it:

```
 await docDbClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(db, coll), myDoc);
```

When the document is stored, it has my documents properties (Id and SomeOtherClass) and an additional `"id"` property (note the lowercase "i"). (and some other technical properties used by documentdb). This is filled with a guid.

As far as I understood, by storing an object which already has an `Id` property, documentdb would use this and not generate it's own (but it did!).

Now I have two problems: I can't check with

```
 await docDbClient.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(db, coll), myDoc.Id);
```

to see if a document already exists, and I can't use the Id property to sort and compare documents in a query like this:

```
IQueryable<MyDocument> query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyDocument>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_account.Database, _account.Collection), queryOptions);
 query = query.Where(x => x.Id.CompareTo(inputValue) >= 0);
```

where inputValue is another key of the same form, to be used for paging. Because when deserializing the object out of documentdb, the `id` property replaces my `Id` property and I never see it's original value.

Am I using this wrong?
Did I make the wrong assumption that my Id property would be used instead of an auto-generated one with lowercase?

---

EDIT: I can confirm that this is solved when using `[JsonProperty("id")]` on the `Id` property. But any document already insertedI can't retrieve my original value of `Id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID field is expected to be "id" lower case.

This would solve it:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Also, there are some issues with NewtonSoft.Json 10.x og CosmosDB/DocumentDB, so you should use a previous version.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I still get "Id" and "id" in the document

Answer (score 2):

DocumentDB's `id` property is what has to be unique. Your own `Id` property (with upper-case I) is not a special property - it's just... a property that you created.

And you've seen the guids auto-generated in the `id` property. Note that you can put your own value in `id`, as long as it's unique. You don't have to accept the default value (guid).

Comment: I understand, but the docs say that you can specify your own value without saying that it has to be json-serialized as (lowercase) `id` or at least that's how I read it. And because of pascal-casing muscle memory I used `Id`. What's weird is that when query-ing, the `Id` property got filled with the contents of `id` and I have no way of retrieving `Id`

Answer (score 2):

CosmosDb only guarantees unique `id` field values for the same partition key.  Therefore, this can exist in the same collection:

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "myPartitionKey": "A",
    ...
},
{
    "id": "12345",
    "myPartitionKey": "B", //different partition key than above
    ...
},
```

but this cannot exist:

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "myPartitionKey": "A",
    ...
},
{
    "id": "12345",
    "myPartitionKey": "A", // Inconceivable! Same id AND partition key as above
    ...
},
```